# PowerPivot Relations - error while creating

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I m trying to create a relation between my database and the table i created to avoid using a Vlookup formula in excel. But i get that error. I want to link account to daily report names. Can anyone tell me how to solve this or why am i getting that error?
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states, you probably have either duplicate entries or blanks in your "Daily Report Names" column. Note that when you bring data into Power Pivot it trims it, so items that are different in Excel due to trailing spaces become duplicates in PP. Also check that you are not bringing through blank rows in your dataset. Highlight a number of rows on the Excel sheet below your dataset and delete the entire rows.